# Not able to print a table in html using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I am simply trying to print a table using javascript but for whatever reason I cannot get it to work. Any advice would be appricated

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
    include 'connect.php';
    function echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches($requestUri)
    {
        $current_file_name = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php");

        if ($current_file_name == $requestUri)
            echo 'class="active"';

    }

    if(isset($_POST['add']))
    {
        header("Location: add_client.php");
        die();
    }

    if(isset($_POST['delete']))
    {

        $DBH = connectDB();
        $trimmed_id = substr($_POST['delete'], 14) ;
        $DBH->exec('DELETE FROM clients where client_ID=' . $trimmed_id);


    }

    if(isset($_POST['modify']))
    {
        $trimmed_id = substr($_POST['modify'], 13);
        header('Location: modify_client.php?client='.$trimmed_id);
        die();
    }

    if(isset($_POST['logout']))
    {
        header("Location: index.php");
        die();
    }

    if(isset($_POST['Print']))
    {


    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Windows and Doors</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text"/javascript">
function printPage() {
 {
        var DocumentContainer = document.getElementById('printTable');
        var WindowObject = window.open('', "TrackHistoryData", 
                              "width=740,height=325,top=200,left=250,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=no");
        WindowObject.document.writeln(DocumentContainer.innerHTML);
        WindowObject.document.close();
        WindowObject.focus();
        WindowObject.print();
        WindowObject.close();
    }
    </script>

    <body background="windows.jpg" >


        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">

          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Windows and Doors</a>
            </div>

            <div>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li <?=echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("homepage")?>>
                    <a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
                <li <?=echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("clientspage")?>>
                    <a href="clients.php">Clients</a></li>
                <li <?=echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("contact")?>>
                    <a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                <li <?=echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("settings")?>>
                    <a href="settings.php">Settings</a></li>
                <li <?=echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("reminder")?>>
                <a href="reminder.php">Reminder</a></li>

              </ul>
            </div>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="searchvalue" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                </div>
             <button type="search" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
            </form> 

          </div>
          <form class="btn pull-right" name="form1" method="post" action="" >

              <input name="logout" type="submit"  value="Logout">
          </form>





        </nav>
        <div class="container" id = "printTable">
            <?php
                    require_once 'connect.php';
                    $DBH = connectDB();
                    session_start();

                    $STH = $DBH->prepare('SELECT * FROM clients');
                    $STH->execute();
            ?>
                <table border= "5px" style="width:1250px" height=200  id="printTable1">
                <th bgcolor="lightgrey"> Select </th>
                <th bgcolor="lightgrey"> ID </th>
                <th bgcolor="lightgrey"> First Name </th>
                <th bgcolor="lightgrey"> Last Name </th>
                <th bgcolor="lightgrey"> Address </th>
                <th bgcolor="lightgrey"> Manufacturer </th>
                <th bgcolor="lightgrey"> Gender </th>   
                <th bgcolor="lightgrey"> Notes </th>
                <th bgcolor="lightgrey"> Delete or modify record</th>

                <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['searchvalue']))
                    {
                        $searchvalue = $_POST['searchvalue'];
                        $STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE client_ID LIKE '%" . $searchvalue . "%' OR first_name LIKE '%" . $searchvalue . "%' OR last_name LIKE '%" . $searchvalue . "%' OR address LIKE '%" . $searchvalue . "%' OR gender LIKE '%" . $searchvalue . "%' OR notes LIKE '%" . $searchvalue . "%' OR manufacturer LIKE '%" . $searchvalue . "%'");
                        $STH->execute();
                        while($result = $STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                    {
                        $manufacturer = $result['manufacturer'];
                        $clientID = $result['client_ID'];
                        $fname = $result['first_name'];
                        $lname = $result['last_name'];
                        $address = $result['address'];
                        $gender = $result['gender'];
                        $notes = $result['notes'];
                ?>

                        <tr bgcolor="lightblue">

                            <td bgcolor="lightblue">
                                <?php echo $clientID ?>
                            </td>
                            <td bgcolor="lightblue">
                                <?php echo $fname ?>
                            </td>
                            <td bgcolor="lightblue">
                                <?php echo $lname ?>
                            </td>
                            <td bgcolor="lightblue">
                                <?php echo $address ?>
                            </td>
                            <td bgcolor="lightblue">
                                <?php echo $manufacturer?>
                            </td>
                            <td bgcolor="lightblue">
                                <?php echo $gender ?>
                            </td>
                            <td bgcolor="lightblue">
                                <?php echo $notes ?>
                            </td>
                            <td bgcolor="lightblue">
                                <form action= "" method="post" role="form">
                                <input type = "submit" name ="delete"  class="btn btn-inverse" value="Delete Client#<?php echo $clientID ?>" >

                                <input type = "submit"  name = "modify" class="btn btn-inverse" value="modifyClient#<?php echo $clientID ?>" >

                            </form>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        <?php 
                    }   

                    }
                    else
                    {   
                        $STH = $DBH->prepare('SELECT * FROM clients');
                        $STH->execute();
                    while($result = $STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                    {
                        $manufacturer = $result['manufacturer'];
                        $clientID = $result['client_ID'];
                        $fname = $result['first_name'];
                        $lname = $result['last_name'];
                        $address = $result['address'];
                        $gender = $result['gender'];
                        $notes = $result['notes'];
                ?>

                        <tr bgcolor="lightblue">
                            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                            <td bgcolor="lightblue">
                                <?php echo $clientID ?>
                            </td>
                            <td bgcolor="lightblue">
                                <?php echo $fname ?>
                            </td>
                            <td bgcolor="lightblue">
                                <?php echo $lname ?>
                            </td>
                            <td bgcolor="lightblue">
                                <?php echo $address ?>
                            </td>
                            <td bgcolor="lightblue">
                                <?php echo $manufacturer?>
                            </td>
                            <td bgcolor="lightblue">
                                <?php echo $gender ?>
                            </td>
                            <td bgcolor="lightblue">
                                <?php echo $notes ?>
                            </td>
                            <td bgcolor="lightblue">
                                <form action= "" method="post" role="form">
                                <input type = "submit" name ="delete" class="btn btn-inverse" value="Delete Client#<?php echo $clientID ?> ">

                                <input type = "submit"  name = "modify" class="btn btn-inverse" value="modifyClient#<?php echo $clientID ?>" >

                            </form>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        <?php 
                    }   }
                        ?>
                </table>

             <form action= "" id="test" method="post" role="form">
            <button name="add" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>


            <input type ="submit" value="Print" onclick="printPage('printTable')"/>
            <button name="SummaryReport" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Summary Report</button>
            </form>



            <div class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom"/>
                <div class = "container">
                    <p class = "navbar-text">Site built by Super Red</p>

            </div>



    </body>
</html>
```

I dont know whether or not it is my print function or some other general error. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: You know what submitting a form does?

Comment: Umh... It sends your form to a server, and if you haven't defined how this server responses, the default action at server is to send the same page back, i.e. your browser reloads the page before it has time to print anything. Why to use a form, if you're not going to need it?

Comment: So basically I just got to change what type of form I'm using and I shouldn't have any more problems? or even just remove it altogether?

Comment: The simplest way is to prevent the submission. Use `input type="button"` for example.

Comment: You may want to make sure that the element you are requesting by id is loaded, before trying to get it.  This link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288923/is-null-after-getelementbyid) could be helpful if this is your problem.

Comment: I had tried that earlier, and i still didn't get any results. That's why my add is in the form of a button but the rest is input type. I was trying different things. I also tried changing the type to button and no luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript" type ="text/javascript" >

function printTbl() {
    var TableToPrint = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1');
    newWin = window.open("");
    newWin.document.write(TableToPrint.outerHTML);
    newWin.print();
    newWin.close();
    return false;
}
```